# Laravel: How to get or search or filter key values in env. file started with s.th

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, microservices, lumen

I want to save my microservice tokens in env. file

SAMPLE:

```
B_SERVICE_TOKENS_SURVEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

B_SERVICE_TOKENS_AUTH=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

B_SERVICE_TOKENS_MESSAGING=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

B_SERVICE_TOKENS_CRM=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I want to get all values that started with "B_SERVICE_TOKENS_"

how can I get all key values or query or filter .env file in laravel?

or any standard way to save these tokens in my environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a file inside the config folder example `b_service.php`

```php
<?php

return [
    'keys' => [ 
        'survey' => env('B_SERVICE_TOKENS_SURVEY', ''),
        'auth' =>  env('B_SERVICE_TOKENS_AUTH', ''), 
    ]
];
```

```php
  $bService = Config::get('b_service.keys');
  // $bService contains all keys;
```

or

```php
  $bService = config('b_service.keys');
```

```
Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-config
```